# Flutter GetX's GetConnect not connecting to http on android

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-getx

I have a Flutter/GetX project that successfully calls http REST APIs from iOS, but does not work from Android.  My AndroidManifest.xml file appears as follows:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.vending_consumer">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    
        <application
            android:label="vending_consumer"
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
            ....
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

So what this should mean is:

- The application has been granted internet access permissions
- The app is enabled for clear text http

Unfortunately, the REST API calls do not work on Android... but work just fine on iOS.

I am using Flutter and GetX, so my provider class appears as follows:

```
    class ConsumerProvider extends GetConnect {
    late String token;
    late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;
    
    ConsumerProvider() {
        timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
        _mainHeaders = {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            };
        }
    
    @override
    void onInit() {
        super.onInit();
        httpClient.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:7001/';
        httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";
        httpClient.timeout = const Duration(seconds: 8);
    }
    
    Future<Consumer> getConsumerByMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) async {
        String url = 'enterprise/masterdata/party/consumers/byMobileNumber/$mobileNumber';
        final Response response = await get(url);
        if (response.status.hasError) {
            debugPrint('[ConsumerProvider getConsumerByMobileNumber] status: ${response.status.code}');
            debugPrint('[ConsumerProvider getConsumerByMobileNumber] response: ${response.body}');
            return Future.error(response.body);
        } else {
            return Consumer.fromJson(response.body);
        }
        }
        ....
    }
```

The response body returned by the GET API is simply null on Android.  The server is never invoked.  This does, however, work just fine on iOS.

Curious if there are additional Flutter or GetX configurations I am missing?  Feedback is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the GetX advice... appreciate the videl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is using "localhost" in my URL.  The iOS Simulator is able to make sense of this, but not the Android Emulator.  Once replacing "localhost" for "192.168.0.x", all works fine.